# Heroku compile issue for assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 5360bb6db5a4334d2c54285cdc87b2b44603c220/static.css.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #<Class:0x007fc369964f18>
       Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 5360bb6db5a4334d2c54285cdc87b2b44603c220/application.css.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #<Class:0x007fc369964f18>
       I, [2014-11-16T00:08:45.210386 #617]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_48a4918221372e4550fe010de2fbfd6f/public/assets/application-692d8d8e1b1dd3eaab947f9c79b2e440.css
       Asset precompilation completed (2.96s)
       Cleaning assets
       Running: rake assets:clean
       I, [2014-11-16T00:08:47.873902 #645]  INFO -- : Removed application-7af893edd04e61e3a7f9d259890ec9f9.css
```

I get the above output when I push a rails app to heroku. What is causing this warning? `can't dump anonymous class #` As a side when I look at the source everything seems be min/obfuscated properly and site appears to work properly too. **So why the error/warning?**

Comment: Doubt this is the same issue, but check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22276991/heroku-error-encountered-while-saving-cache

Comment: Thanks @Alec, I will post an update if that answer helps me solve the issue I'm having.