# Heroku can't dump anonymous classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I didn't really understand the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578956/sass-error-in-rails-app-on-heroku-cant-dump-anonymous-class) question, and the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22276991/heroku-error-encountered-while-saving-cache) question didn't work for me.

Running Heroku push got some errors, and running `heroku run bundle exec rake assets:precompile` gave all the "can't dump anonymous class" errors.

Here's my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.1'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.5'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'sass', '3.2.5'
group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: If whoever downvoted this question could tell me why they downvoted that would be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `rake assets:precompile` failed locally, I looked up the error which was `undefined method`environment' for nil:NilClass` and the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392862/undefined-method-environment-for-nilnilclass-when-importing-bootstrap) led me in the right direction.

In the end, this configuration worked for me:

`gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'`

After that, I ran `rake assets:precompile` and it works!