# Heroku Warning. Error encountered while saving cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I got this error trying to run my app on heroku.

```
Running: rake assets:precompile
       I, [2014-10-22T07:17:25.188024 #1769]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_4ece09d11c2d4c179d14902c8b9779df/public/assets/application-1b2d12a92131e3a2c48555d54cda55f3.js
       Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 5be2542a53a8c1772a5fdfc23bc1e1f4af55b170/custom.css.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #<Class:0x007f309e4ea5e0>
       Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 62fc6d960148791fef39ec24624f8ec503a8bfd5/_bootstrap-sprockets.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #<Class:0x007f309e4ea5e0>
       Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 62fc6d960148791fef39ec24624f8ec503a8bfd5/_bootstrap.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #<Class:0x007f309e4ea5e0>
       .....
```

I know there are other questions very similar to this however their answers are from the past and I have a different Sass version than them. Not sure if there is already a fix out for this current issue.

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason can be missing sass or sass-rails gem. 
Have a look at this, solves quite a similar issue.
[sass error in rails app on heroku: can't dump anonymous class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578956/sass-error-in-rails-app-on-heroku-cant-dump-anonymous-class)